# Не сбрасываются переменные объявленные в другой процедуре Delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Не сбрасываются переменные объявленные в другой процедуре, как `const sumHum:integer=0;`
(Сброс происходит в той же форме, но в другой процедуре)(в `public` объявлен)

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   r:TModalResult; 
begin
r :=MessageDlg('сбросить счет?',
                            mtCustom, [mbYes,mbNo], 0);
 if r=mrYes then
  begin
    //Label6.Caption := '0';
    //Label7.Caption := '0';
    sumHum := 0;
    sumComp := 0;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зря я Вам про них рассказал :).

У Вас эти переменные (`sumHum` и `sumComp`) объявлены два раза в разных местах. Один раз - как локальные статические в процедуре, второй раз - как члены классa формы (или глобальные). Это совершенно разные переменные, изменение значений одних не влияет на другие. Скорее всего, Вам надо убрать локальные переменные и работать с членами класса.

Comment: убрал их из процедуры и оставил в `puplic`, все работает!